# Rails, Paperclip, Amazon S3, and Rspec testing - user.avatar object not being set to nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, amazon-s3, rspec, paperclip

So I have a setup with Paperclip, Amazon S3, and I'm testing with RSPEC trying to delete the User.avatar object.

My delete method is:

```
@user.avatar.clear
@user.avatar.destroy
@user.avatar = nil
@user.save
```

Yes, I realize I have essentially 3 deletion methods in there. But here's my point - when I run

```
@user.avatar
```

it still returns

```
=> #<Paperclip::Attachment ...@name=
```

I'm trying to write a test where I delete the attachment and my expect block expects @user.avatar = nil. However, it is not getting = to nil.

How should I be testing for the deletion of the avatar?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Paperclip::Atachment#exists?` method

You can write the assertion on your test like this:

```
expect(user.avatar.exists?).to be(false)
```

Answer (score 0):

As @Manuel said you have to use `expect(@user.avatar.exists?).to be(false)` after deleting the `avatar` by this code

`@user.avatar = nil
 @user.save`

On calling of `@user.avatar` will always return a default `Hash` of paperclip class, So you have to check the presentability by specific method
Like: `Paperclip::Atachment#exists?` or `@user.avatar.nil?` or `@user.avatar.present?` etc

Hope you find this helpful.